# Hibernate Interceptor Not Working

Tags: spring, hibernate, interceptor

I have a simple HibernateInterceptor in which basically I want to set a few fields automatically. This interceptor (shown below) extends EmptyInterceptor:

```
public class EntityAuditInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    /**
     * The Serial Version UUID.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4636626262147801287L;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor#onFlushDirty(java.lang.Object, java.io.Serializable, java.lang.Object[], java.lang.Object[], java.lang.String[], org.hibernate.type.Type[])
     */
    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity,  Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {

        // doing stuff here

        return false;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor#onSave(java.lang.Object, java.io.Serializable, java.lang.Object[], java.lang.String[], org.hibernate.type.Type[])
     */
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {

                // doing stuff here
        return false;
    } 
}
```

I am wiring using a spring config file as follows:

```
<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="hsqlDbDataSource"/>

        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.dreamteam.lms.**.*</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <!-- Adding Interceptor here -->
        <property name="entityInterceptor">
            <bean class="com.dreamteam.lms.interceptors.EntityAuditInterceptor"></bean>
        </property>


        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <!--<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>-->
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

However, the Interceptor is never reached. Does anyone have any clue? I have also tried adding the following to the transaction manager bean definition as follows:

```
<property name="entityInterceptor">
        <ref local="entityAuditInterceptor"/>
    </property>
```

Answer (score 14):

Ok, just for the record, I solved this problem which turned out to be a stupid mistake from my part.

When I implemented my interceptor that extends EmptyInterceptor I added the method 'onFlushDirty' and so on. So far so good. The problem was that on using my IDE to auto-import the used classes, I ended up importing java.reflect.Type instead of org.hibernate.type.Type by mistake. Hence, I was not really overriding the interceptor method!

I noticed that when I added the @Override interceptor to my method.

Another mystery solved ... :)

Comment: @Kros may you look at very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602318/hibernate-myinterceptoronflushdirty-is-never-called pls?

Comment: I've had the same problem -  java.reflect.Type instead of org.hibernate.type. Fortunately I've found this answer!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Spring XML configuration is correct, so Hibernate should be calling your interceptor methods. However those methods appear to always return `false` which means that Hibernate will ignore any changes you make.

When you change a value you must return `true`. For example, this code iterates through all the properties and returns `true` if and only if a change is made:

```
public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity,  Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    boolean changed = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < propertyNames.length; i++) {
        if ("saveDate".equals(propertyNames[i])) {
            currentState[i] = new Date();
            changed = true;
        }
    }
    return changed;
}
```

Comment: Hi gutch ... I have commented out parts of the code so that the question here is shorter. My problem is that it does not enter the interceptor at all. I have placed a breakpoint in the interceptor. Yet, it is never executed. I am really clueless.

Comment: @gutch could you look at very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602318/hibernate-myinterceptoronflushdirty-is-never-called pls?